# JS: React and global namespace pollution

Tags: javascript, namespaces, reactjs

I'm considering to use react in a new website and I'm still wondering, how to handle the global namespace with react components. For example, if I define several React Components like this:

```
var MySlider = React.createClass({ // snip });
var MyAlert = React.createClass({ // snip });
var MyDropdown = React.createClass({ // snip });
```

Rendering a component would look like this:

```
React.renderComponent(
    <MySlider />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

However, I'd prefer to namespace my components to avoid polluting the global namespace.

```
var Namespace = {};
Namespace.MySlider = React.createClass({ // snip });
```

When it comes to rendering, the component is not found due to namespacing, I guess.

```
React.renderComponent(
    <Namespace.MySlider />, // component is not found
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

What am I missing here? Just ignore global namespace pollution? Or is there a possibility to namespace your components?

Thanks!

Comment: Right now that syntax doesn't work but may in the future. ssorallen's answer is correct; module systems are recommended.

Comment: As @BenAlpert alluded to earlier, [JSX namespacing](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html#jsx-namespacing) was added in React 0.11.0. It is still recommended to use a module loader, but you can now use namespaces as you were hoping to in your example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not exactly a React JS question since any large JavaScript codebase has to deal with module loading. I suggest forgoing namespacing in JavaScript the way you started to approach it and instead use a module loader.

You will get many opinions on this, but look at some of the widely-used module loaders:

- [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)
- [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/)
- [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll definitely take a look.

Answer (score 6):

this code is work.

```
React.renderComponent(
    Namespace.MySlider(),
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

See the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) for more information.