# What is the best way to do Namespaced Components in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I need to use this method to create form elements component set, But still I don't have an idea of how to do this with ES6. So could anyone can tell me how to do this with ES6?

```
var MyFormComponent = React.createClass({ ... });

MyFormComponent.Row = React.createClass({ ... });
MyFormComponent.Label = React.createClass({ ... });
MyFormComponent.Input = React.createClass({ ... });
```

**Usage:**

```
var Form = MyFormComponent;

var App = (
  <Form>
    <Form.Row>
      <Form.Label />
      <Form.Input />
    </Form.Row>
  </Form>
);
```

Comment: You mean es3 namespaces? With creating `my.global.something`? With es6 you should separate your code to modules and then use [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: useful link is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499678/js-react-and-global-namespace-pollution)